# Setting to query only Default Graph and exclude Named Graphs

Tags: graphdb, named-graphs

In the GraphDB documentation, I see that "the dataset’s default graph contains the merge of the database’s default graph AND all the database named graphs." This means that "if a statement `ex:x ex:y ex:z` exists in the database in the graph `ex:g`" then a query such as `SELECT * { ?s ?p ?o }` will return the triple `ex:x ex:y ex:z`

I am wondering if there is a setting which can be triggered either via the web interface or via the RDF4J/OpenRDF API which will disable this behavior in a specified GraphDB repository. That is, for the purposes of my project I would prefer to have triples which are stored in named graphs to only appear in results which specifically query that named graph.

I have not seen anything like this searching through the documentation or on the settings available on the web interface, but maybe somebody here knows something I don't.

EDIT: I am not looking for a SPARQL solution to this problem. I know that I can query just the default graph using SPARQL, but I want to be able to use the query `SELECT * { ?s ?p ?o }` and only see results which are in the default graph by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GraphDB/RDF4J have a different interpretation than Jena [how to query the default graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18366298/single-quad-most-basic-sparql-query-1-result-in-jena-2-results-in-sesame). The only easy way to query only explicit statements in the default graph is to use the special graph `sesame:nil`. The SPARQL-based solution is to write:

```
PREFIX sesame: <http://www.openrdf.org/schema/sesame#>
SELECT ?s ?p ?o
FROM sesame:nil
WHERE {
   ?s ?p ?o .
} LIMIT 100
```

I don't think there is any easy non-SPARQL based solution like changing a configuration option or even use this special graph over the SPARQL Graph Store protocol.